# ASP.NET MVC 4 w/Code First Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, ef-code-first

I'm looking for a complete tutorial that will explain Code First Entity Framework MVC4 with SQL database. The tutorials I have seen so far are either in c# or use LocalDB. I'm unsure on how to change from LocalDB to SQL server, so I want to start with a tutorial that does SQL server.

I'm not new to MVC. I've been working with a framework that involves Backbone.js and ASP.NET MVC, but I am not sure how to replicate that exactly, so I'm looking for a tutorial that teaches me how to make an application in MVC4 using SQL Server and Code First Entity Framework in VB.NET

Thanks

Comment: This question is pretty broad and likely to be put on hold. You should  try doing research on your topic, trying some things on your own, and asking questions about specific issues you have in implementation.

Comment: Well, I looked quite a bit for a good tutorial and found a few on MSDN. However, they were either not implementing code first entity framework, or were using the wrong db. I thought about just diving into it, but I didn't want to waste time doing things the wrong way and spending time on the internet looking for stuff a tutorial would already teach.

Comment: You just need to change connection string from localdb to sql. It has no influence on CodeFirst approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between writing the code to use localDb or SQLSERVER--or Oracle, mysql, postgresql or anything else that has an ADO.NET connector. I usually do my initial design and test with a localDB connection string. Then when I am ready to deploy to the UnitTesting Server, Staging, and Production, I swap out the connection string to a SQLServer connection string. That is all there is to it.

You can simply use the LocalDb tutorials with a different connection string.

I got started [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907).

Comment: Thanks! Can you guys show me how I can swap it out?

Comment: Do some reading, it isn't hard. Here is a good starting point. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254978.aspx